# Get from which table is field

Tags: mysql, structure

Have a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id_table1 = t1.id
LIMIT 1
```

Got result:

```
id => 1
field1 => val1
filed2 => val2
field3 => val3
```

Is it possible to know which filed belongs to which table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need: [mysql_fetch_field()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php)

Comment: Thanks i works. Just need to add what function exists for [Mysqli](http://am1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) and [PDO](http://am1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$export =mysql_query("SELECT fieldnames FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON 
t2.id_table1 = t1.id LIMIT 1");

$no_rows= mysql_num_rows ( $export );
for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields-1; $i++ ) 
{
    $fields=mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . ",";
}

echo $fields;
```

Please Try this...